# override field alias from subclass in Pydantic

Tags: python, pydantic

I have 2 models, 1 subclassing the other:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List

class Model1(BaseModel):
    names: List[str]

class Model2(Model1):
    # define here an alias for names -> e.g. "firstnames"
    pass

data = { "names": ["rodrigo", "julien", "matthew", "bob"] }
# Model1(**data).dict()  -> gives {'names': ['rodrigo', 'julien', 'matthew', 'bob']}
# Model2(**data).dict()  -> gives {'firstnames':  ['rodrigo', 'julien', 'matthew', 'bob']}
```

How can I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to subclass to accomplish what you want (unless your need is more complex than your example).

**For import:** Add the `Config` option to `allow_population_by_field_name` so you can add the data with `names` or `firstnames`

**For export:** Add `by_alias=True` to the `dict()` method to control the output

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List


class Model(BaseModel):
    names: List[str] = Field(alias="firstnames")

    class Config:
        allow_population_by_field_name = True


def main():
    data = {"names": ["rodrigo", "julien", "matthew", "bob"]}
    model = Model(**data)
    print(model.dict())
    print(model.dict(by_alias=True))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

yields:

```py
{'names': ['rodrigo', 'julien', 'matthew', 'bob']}
{'firstnames': ['rodrigo', 'julien', 'matthew', 'bob']}
```

Comment: Exactly what I ended up doing meanwhile. Cool to see I did share the same path from what you describe. Though I actually needed more logic so I subclassed the model anyway though. Adding also in the child class ```fields = {"names":"firstnames"}``` so to convert to "firstnames" when by_alias=True only when it is towards this child model and not the parent instantiated. What are your thoughts on that?

Comment: It sounds like, for your domain, that makes a lot of sense, and is a good solution!